# Kubernetes Node Affinity and statefulsets

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

I'm looking to create a statefulset using affinity. I have added a label to my 3 nodes. Two of them have area=area1 and one node has area=area2. I'm looking to run my statefulset pods only on the nodes with area=area1. It's not working. I'm getting an error from the scheduler that no nodes were matched. I'm running Kubernetes v1.7.4

Yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: stateful-bcs
spec:
  serviceName: mybcs
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
       app: simplecount
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: area
                operator: In
                values:
                - area1
      containers:
        - name: test1
          image: XXXX.azurecr.io/simple
          env:
            - name: SIMPLE_SERVICE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
         command:
            - ./simplecount
            - "$(SIMPLE_SERVICE_NAME)"
      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: XXXXXXX
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Silly question but why not simply use the `nodeSelector` (cf. `kubectl explain statefulset.spec.template.spec.nodeSelector`) to pin pods to a certain node?

Comment: We are going to need the affinity/anti-affinity settings. We need to specify service instances to be deployed to different boxes, anti-affinity on pods, for high availability. We want to deploy service sets to machine "areas" so that services are running close to resources they manage. For the node affinity we could use node selector. We can't use node selector for pod anti-affinity. Thought I would start with the "easy" case of using node affinity.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas never knew explain command. this helped me solving a validation error i've been struggling for hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You should be using `nodeAffinity` not `podAffinity`, `podAffinity` is "based on labels on pods that are already running on the node rather than based on labels on nodes" (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/).